# Is 各行各业 equivalent to “all walks of life”?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-meaning

各行各业 was from of Google Translate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

各行各业 ( = 各行业) means "various industries" e.g. 造船业、旅游业、演艺行业

“all walks of life” is much broader

> Definition of [all walks of life](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20walks%20of%20life)

> —used to refer to people who have many different jobs or **positions in society**

That includes not only people with different kinds of jobs, but also includes the rich and the poor, the leader and the follower the elder and the youth, the respected and the disrespected. I would translate "all walks of life" as 各阶层人士

*Google Translate: 各阶层(人士) --> (People) from all walks of life*

Example of 各阶层:

示威者来自(社会)**各阶层**  - Demonstrators come from **all walks of life** (in society)

示威者包括**各阶层人士**  - The demonstrators included **people from all walks of life**

(former police, teacher, carpenter, factory worker, farmer, business owner, full-time housewife, student, homeless person, retiree, etc. In short- people who live all different kinds of life)

Example of 各行各业:

各行各业都受影响 - various industries are affected

Comment: I feel 各阶层 isn't fit for the English definition of "all walks of life". 各阶层 refers to the aspect of different classes or levels such as 工人阶层, 农民阶层, etc. It doesn't reflect the different kind of jobs or positions. Well, 各行各业 refers to different job categories, such as 服装业, 食品加工业, etc. Maybe, "各行各业, 各种职位" is more appropriate for "all walks of life". So, "people from all walks of life" can be "各行各业，不同岗位的人士".

Comment: “all walks of life” is much broader:  agreed.

Comment: 阶級 is social classes; 阶层 is social groups ; 层 -->层面; 級 -->級別

Answer (score 2):

Sounds the same to me.
"People from all walks of life" can be translated as "各行各业的人们"

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes".

各行 - each way of make living; 各业 - each type of work/job. The two combined equals to "all ways of making living" that is the same as "all walks of life".